# Check whether a form date field is equal to 1899-12-30 00:00:00.000

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime

I know this should be simple but after hours of googling I am still failing...

I have a vb.net form application. Basically I have an SQL database with an Employee table with an EmpFinish column in datetime, null format (Employee Finish Date). The data is imported from a linked SQL DB (populated from an external app). Any "blank" dates show as 1899-12-30 00:00:00.000 in SQL.

The Employee table data is shown on a datagridview form, a row is selected, then I want to perform a check to test whether that rows EmpFinish date from the form is earlier or equal to today and is not equal to it's "blank" value i.e. has the employee left employment.

Code excerpt:

```vb
Dim currentDateTime = DateTime.Now

Dim selectedEmpFinishDate As DateTime = 
    EmployeesDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value

If selectedEmpFinishDate.CompareTo(currentDateTime) <= 0 Then

    ' code to do

End If
```

I didn't start out using the CompareTo() above util I started Googling this issue and it seems this is the best way to compare dates. Yes???

This test works for actual dates e.g. yesterday but also catches all 1899 dates, I have tried lots of tests (using 1 If statement of separate ones) to check for the 1899 blank dates but cannot get anything to work. If I debug the code at the test line, selectedEmpFinishDate supposedly equals #12/30/1899#. If I show the field value onscreen via
MsgBox("selectedFinDate = " & selectedEmpFinishDate) it reports as 00:00:00

I know this must be possible but cannot figure it out.

Could someone please offer a solution as I am running out of hair to pull out.

Comment: `Any "blank" dates show as 1899-12-30 00:00:00.000 in SQL.` why? If it's undefined, make sure the column allows nulls. If I were you I'd make the schema change if necessary, and update all those dates with NULL, and make sure 1899 doesn't get back in there.

Comment: Start by reading [ask] and taking the [tour].  Then turn on `Option Strict` - DGV cells never ever return a `DateTime` value.  `1899-12-30` seems like a magic value indicating not-set, you should be able to just see if the `DateTime` is less than `#1/1/1900#` or even `1/1/2001`

Comment: I think 1899-12-30 is the zero-date in VB6 or VBA.
Are you sure that you work in VB.NET and not in VB6 or VBA?
Because changing the date 1899-12-30 to 00:00:00 when displaying is usually a VB6/VBA thing.

You can use the < or > operator when comparing dates, so your line of code should be equivalent to `If selectedEmpFinishDate < currentDateTime Then...`

Answer (score 0):

I have followed djv's advice (I had the same thought last night) and done an override to set these date values to NULL. I was then able to use IsDBNull() successfully.
To clarify where these dates came from... Data is imported into this database from another SQL DB created by a huge business software application. Not sure if they want the dates stored this way or whether the import sets them to be this "blank" default 1899 date. 
They actually showed on all forms as 1899 etc so resetting them to NULL is the best option all around.
To anyone else who has these 1899 dates I would advise to update them to NULL.
Thank you to everyone who responded especially djv.